# Problem to find element with appium, application is running - appium oen application

Tags: appium, elements

I have a problem with testing of aúúlivation.
I have this code for net CORE using MS test net.CORE.
public class IPTV

```
{
    static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> Sessions;


    [ClassInitialize]

    public static void BeforeTest(TestContext testContext)
    {
        AppiumOptions appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();

        appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"C:\Users\renata.cikova\Desktop\IPTVManagement\Colosseo.IPTVManagement.exe");
        //appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Windows");
        // appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "cikova-pc");
        Sessions = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"), appiumOptions);
        Sessions.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25);
        // Session.Manage().Window().Maximize();



    }

    
    [TestMethod]
    public void UnsucessLogin()
    {
        if (Sessions.CurrentWindowHandle != Sessions.WindowHandles.Last())
        {
            Sessions.SwitchTo().Window(Sessions.WindowHandles.Last());
        }
        Sessions.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);
                   
        var textbox = Sessions.FindElementByClassName("RadBusyIndicator").FindElementByClassName("TextBox");
        textbox.SendKeys("Admin");
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        var password = Sessions.FindElementByClassName("PasswordBox");
        password.SendKeys("Admin");
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Sessions.FindElementByName("Login").Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        //var text = Session.FindElementByName("Unknown error").Text;
        //Console.WriteLine(text);
      //  Assert.AreEqual(text, "Unknown error");
        

    }
```

Appium open application, but can't find any elements of the application.
What I have wrong?
I haved installed web driver client, I am using UI recorder to identify the elements, so I definitely don`t know where is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> var textbox = Sessions.FindElementByClassName("RadBusyIndicator").FindElementByClassName("TextBox");

It looks like you are not using [FindElement](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-element/) correctly.

> Class name - For IOS it is the full name of the XCUI element and begins with XCUIElementType. For Android it is the full name of the UIAutomator2 class (e.g.: android.widget.TextView)